# I cant get my state to update using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am trying to update my state with the `onClick` event. The `onClick` executes but fails to update the state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [sixBreaks, setSixTotal] = useState({
    breaks: 11,
    screen: 15,
    hindge: 5
  });
  const update = () => {
    return setSixTotal(sixBreaks.breaks + 1)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Total Broken: {sixBreaks.breaks}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => update()}>
        CLICK ME TO INCREMENT
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

`sixBreaks` is an object, you will have to update the entire object in order to update the `breaks` state.

```
const update = () => {
  setSixTotal({ 
    ...sixBreaks, 
    breaks: sixBreaks.breaks + 1 
  });
};
```

Doing `setSixTotal(sixBreaks.breaks + 1)` will not propertly update your `breaks` state, as that implies that you are overwriting your `state` with the values of the `breaks` key.

Answer (score 0):

Use the spread operator to update to update the values on your object properties. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
const update = () => {
    return setSixTotal({...sixBreaks, {breaks: sixBreaks.breaks + 1}})
}
```

or use the Object.assign function like this:

```
const update = () => {
        const updatedValue = Object.assign({}, sixBreaks, {breaks: sixBreaks.breaks + 1})
        return setSixTotal(updatedValue)
    }
```

So update your code like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    import logo from "./logo.svg";
    import "./App.css";

    function App() {
      const [sixBreaks, setSixTotal] = useState({
        breaks: 11,
        screen: 15,
        hindge: 5
      });
      const update = () => {
        setSixTotal({...sixBreaks, {breaks: sixBreaks.breaks + 1}})
      }
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Total Broken: {sixBreaks.breaks}</h1>
          <button onClick={() => update()}>
            CLICK ME TO INCREMENT
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
const update = () => {
  return setSixTotal(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    breaks: prev.breaks + 1
  }));
};
```

Don't use the `sixBreaks.breaks` directly since React won't guarantee that it will be the same at the time of update but rather use the callback style as I wrote above to avoid bugs